# MYSQL IN only returning first row

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel, sequelpro

I have read several posts about similar issues but all of them were problems in the code while mine even occurs in the mysql sequel console.

my query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ("1,2") ORDER BY id DESC`

My Users table currently contains two users - one with id 1 and the other one with id 2 so actually both should be returned.
Unfortunately only the first row gets returned

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2) ORDER BY id DESC try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IN` operator does not parse strings, leave out the double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: And just to add a little more explanation: the reason it **is** matching user ID=1 is because MySQL parses the string "1,2" into the number "1" (ie. it ignores the comma and everything after it).